# htaccess different 404 on wordpress subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a `Wordpress`installation at the sub-folder `www.example.com/blog` of my domain. It has it's own 404 page which unfortunately also shows if a page can't be found on my main website.

I'd like to have a `404` redirection of my main Website and the Wordpress one for my blog in the subfolder.

This is the code I have until now. But the second one is overwriting the first. How can I make the wordpress redirection only apply to the subfolder?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound/404.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if your main website is www.domain.com and your WP blog is www.domain.com/blog then why both WP and non-WP rules are in the same .htaccess file?
I mean, your WP in a subfolder should have its .htaccess in that same subfolder, while the main website has a different .htaccess in root folder.

EDIT: assuming that the main website is not WP, you should have 2 different .htaccess files. The first one with non-WP rules goes to main website directory and looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound/404.html
```

The second is just a regular WP .htaccess file and goes to WP directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: Ah ok, I've put the Wordpress code to /blog. But my blog stops working then. Do you know how I need to change the code then?

Comment: Ok, can you post contentss of .htaccess that's in the main website folder and the one which is in WP blog folder?

Comment: So the first 4 Lines would be for the main website:
`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound/404.html`

And the other part would be for Wordpress:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: ok, i don't know why, but I overwrote the .htaccess file with the same code from the wordpress settings and now it woks... I couldn't find any difference in the code.

Comment: So what exactly you're saying is now working for you?

Comment: sorry for being unprecise:

I created a .htaccess file for my main website and added the 4 first lines of the example. Then I created a second .htaccess file with the rest of the code (the wordpress code) and put it into my blog subfolder. And now everything works fine. :)

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I was expecting. Thanks for clarifying though ;) I'll edit my initial reply.